# Calculating the Prior and Posterior Mean

Tags: bayesian, prior, posterior

I was recently asked to calculate the prior mean and posterior mean of the proportion of defective items in a production line assuming a uniform prior for this proportion. The question was stating that I got 30 samples and 3 are defective. How does that change the prior mean and posterior mean?

How do I need to approach this question?

Comment: The prior distribution is $U(0, 1)$, right?

Comment: This question needs a 'self-study' tag.

Comment: Ideally, the prior distribution is chosen before the data are available, so the data have no influence on the choice of the prior distribution. Bayes' Theorem shows how to put the prior distribution and the data together to get a posterior distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the *success* probability be $\theta,$ and the symbol $\propto$ (read as "proportional to") indicate the the 'kernels' of density functions are used (density functions without norming constants).

Prior distribution is $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1) \equiv \mathsf{Beta}(1,1),$ which has mean $1/2.$ This prior distribution has density $f(\theta) \propto \theta^{1-1}(1-\theta)^{1-1} = 1.$

For the data you give, the binomial likelihood is $g(x|\theta) \propto \theta^{27}(1-\theta)^3.$

Thus, by Bayes' Theorem, the posterior distribution is
$$h(\theta|x) = f(\theta)\times g(x|\theta) \\
\propto \theta^{28-1}(1-\theta)^{4-1},$$

where one can see that the posterior distribution
has the kernel of $\mathsf{Beta}(28,4).$
Can you see that this is the posterior distribution and that it has mean $0.875?$
If you are not familiar with beta distribution, see your text, class notes, or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).

[When the prior and likelihood
are mathematically compatible in this way, making it easy to identify
The posterior distribution, one says they are 'conjugate'.]

*Note:* If you want a Bayesian posterior 95% credible interval for
$\theta,$ a computation in R gives $(0.710, 0.947).$

```
qbeta(c(.025, .975), 28, 5)
[1] 0.7100516 0.9472494
```

For comparison, a popular style of frequentist confidence interval for $\theta$
is $(0.734, 0.972).$ Although the Bayesian credible interval and the frequentist confidence interval are *numerically* similar, you should
be sure you understand that their *interpretations* are quite different.
The frequentist CI is interpreted in terms of the long run properties of intervals made in a similar way. The Bayesian credible interval refers to the specific problem at hand, in view of the prior distribution used.

```
p.est = (27+2)/(30+4)
AC.CI = p.est + qnorm(c(.025,.975))*sqrt(p.est*(1-p.est)/34)
AC.CI
[1] 0.7338955 0.9719869
```